# When constructing a row on the fly, does jQuery mutate the DOM multiple times?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Consider the following code:

```
$('.widget').find('tbody')
  .append($('<tr>')
    .append($('<td>')
    )
    .append($('<td>')
      .text('Median Values')
    )
    .append($('<td>')
      .text(5)
    )
    .append($('<td>')
      .text(6)
    )
    .append($('<td>')
      .text(7)
    )
    .append($('<td>')
      .text(8)
    )
    .append($('<td>')
      .text(4.2)
    )
  );
```

In this case does jQuery mutate the DOM multiple times or just once?  Should I construct a `<tr>` in memory and then append it to `$('.widget').find('tbody')`?

Comment: [looking at this](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/68538/), I think it makes clear that multiple mutations happen

Comment: In this case it will only manipulate the DOM once, since you are only appending to a DOM element once.  https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/68559/

Comment: @baao how does that jive with dave's MutationObserver?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case it will only manipulate the DOM once, since you are only appending to a DOM element once.  We can use a `MutationObserver` to verify this:

```js
var i = 0;
var observeDOM = (function() {
  var MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver,
    eventListenerSupported = window.addEventListener;

  return function(obj, callback) {
    if (MutationObserver) {
      // define a new observer
      var obs = new MutationObserver(function(mutations, observer) {
        if (mutations[0].addedNodes.length || mutations[0].removedNodes.length)
          callback();
      });
      // have the observer observe foo for changes in children
      obs.observe(obj, {
        childList: true,
        subtree: true
      });
    } else if (eventListenerSupported) {
      obj.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', callback, false);
      obj.addEventListener('DOMNodeRemoved', callback, false);
    }
  };
})();

// Observe a specific DOM element:
observeDOM(document.getElementById('widget'), function() {
  i++;
  console.log('dom changed ' + i + ' times');
});

$('#widget').find('tbody')
  .append($('<tr>')
    .append($('<td>'))
    .append($('<td>')
      .text('Median Values')
    )
    .append($('<td>')
      .text(5)
    )
    .append($('<td>')
      .text(6)
    )
    .append($('<td>')
      .text(7)
    )
    .append($('<td>')
      .text(8)
    )
    .append($('<td>')
      .text(4.2)
    )
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="widget">
  <table>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Not only did I get an answer, but also learned something new about the ability to observe DOM mutations!!!  Thank you.